# Overlaying two graphs using viewports

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, viewport

I've been trying (knowing all the reasons why I shouldn't) to overlay two graphs on each other. I remember that when I used viewports in the past the two images would overlay on top of each other. So `grid` wouldn't overwrite one graphic with the other. In the MWE below, one graphic is deleted when I try and print the second over it.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

date=seq(as.Date('2012-04-01',"%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date('2013-03-27','%Y-%m-%d'),1)
tp1=data.frame(Date=date,bond=rnorm(361,100,2),equity=rnorm(361,60,15))
vp=viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,height=1,width=1)
a = ggplot(tp1,aes(Date,bond)) + geom_line(colour=I("blue")) + xlim(range(tp1$Date))
b = ggplot(tp1,aes(Date,equity)) + geom_line(colour=I("red")) + xlim(range(tp1$Date))
print(a,vp=vp)
print(b,vp=vp)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't run. We're missing ablue1 and 2.

Comment: Darn. Sorry. Didn't notice those. editing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how using just viewports you can overlay the 2 ggplot2 plots. Maybe you did this using some simple grid graphics, not with ggplot2 plots that are complex (many viewports with a lot of details). Viewports are just a context where you basically define the dimensions/scales of your plot.

[Here](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2), a hadley code doing what you want. I just  add a small part and adapt it using your plot instructions.

[image]

The all code is :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

grid.newpage()

# two plots
a = ggplot(tp1,aes(Date,bond)) + geom_line(colour=I("blue")) + xlim(range(tp1$Date))
b = ggplot(tp1,aes(Date,equity)) + 
  geom_line(colour=I("red")) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA))

# extract gtable
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(b))

# overlap the panel of 2nd plot on that of 1st plot
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, 
                     pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

## what I dd is to plot a new viewports.
vp=viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,height=0.5,width=0.5)
pushViewport(vp)
grid.draw(g)
upViewport()
```

Comment: thanks @agstudy. This will work. Do you happen to know where I can find the documentation on `ggplot_ggtable` and `ggplot_build`? I've been looking and haven't been able to locate anything on the web.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha, did you want 2 y-axis? Your data are not under the same scale, yet there's only 1 y-axis.

Comment: @Arun yes ! good idea. maybe I will do after ( a little bit busy now)

Comment: @Arun, thanks . I've used `rescale` and `ggplot(...,aes(...group=id))`. I was looking for a different way. Happy to hear of another one if you have it in mind...

Comment: @agstudy, no issues. I was thinking of: `ggplot(melt(tp1, id.var="Date"), aes(x=Date, y = value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()` but that *does not* give the same plot as the values are not on the same scale (one's around 100 and the other's around 50). Which makes me wonder, shouldn't the plot then have 2 Y-axis (similar to the one you linked here).

Comment: @TahnoonPasha, if you've rescaled data, then load `require(reshape2)` package and then try the code above.

Comment: @Arun ! yes next step is to set y-axis (here I moit it), but this is very hard to do using `ggplot2` (it is not the philosophy of the package).