# R documentation on ggplot_gtable and ggplot_build

Tags: r, ggplot2

I seem to be coming across the `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(graph))` commands a lot these days when I research how to modify my ggplot graph in a particular way.

For example [how to add a data table to a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826831/r-adding-a-datatable-to-a-ggplot-graph-using-viewports-scaling-the-grob) or [how to overlay two graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262405/overlaying-two-graphs-using-viewports) or [How to add a line to a graph outside the plot area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525957/how-to-draw-lines-outside-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2)

I'd like to learn more and I understand that the commands are part of the base ggplot2 package but I can't find anything in the docs or my searches on them. Does anyone know where I can find more information on these commands and the tree structure of the list they create?

Thanks

Comment: browsing the source code, probably

Comment: Thanks @baptiste I should have said as a neophyte.. :-)

Comment: Both functions are documented in my version of ggplot. Perhaps you should upgrade? But in general, the documentation and the source code are probably the only answers.

Comment: thanks @joran I get a rudimentary comment from `?ggplot_gtable` e.g and I'm on ggplot2 0.9.3 but it doesn't say much. I suspect you're right, but I had hoped it may have been listed somewhere in the nether depths of Hadleys ggplot site that I was unaware of...

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/plot-render.r

Comment: thanks for the pointer @hadley. That makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these links will help you out:

[ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)

[ggplot_gtable documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggplot2/docs/ggplot_gtable)

[And a few ggplot examples](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~mikeck/?p=407)